# What is an *.rsd file on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I downloaded an App and it contained an *.rsd file. What's that?

Comment: What app exactly? Some more context please :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing which App you downloaded, I'd guess it's probably a RealSQLDatabase file, which is used by REALBasic applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could see what [`file`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) has to say.